# adding multiple cards in a html without using seperate div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can someone help me out how to generate multiple cards in HTML without adding separate div for each card? the thing is I want the code length to be shorter so I want to use single that is applicable to shorten the length and generate the cards to display in a HTML page.As I'm new to development I'm not able to solve this problem in spite of many searches.

Comment: What is a card?

Comment: it is an oblect on which we can display some content.@almostabeginner

Comment: You mean it is a layout? I think it would help if you post the css and html.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to understand what your trying to ask.@almostabeginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col m4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-wallpapers/download/2268/Square-Pattern-ipad-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg">
        <span class="card-title" style="width:100%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">Sample1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col m4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-wallpapers/download/2268/Square-Pattern-ipad-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg">
        <span class="card-title" style="width:100%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">Sample2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fixed-action-btn click-to-toggle" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <i class="large material-icons">menu</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn-floating red" class="fbtn" href="test.html"><i class="material-icons">home</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1" class="fbtn" href="#"><i class="material-icons">work</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating green" class="fbtn" href="about.html"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating blue" class="fbtn" href="contact.html"><i class="material-icons">speaker_notes</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear" style="clear:both; height: 100px;">
</div>
<footer class="ui-footer" style="background:#fafafa; width:100%; position:fixed; z-index:99; clear:both;">
  <div class="container">
    <p>&copy; Yogesh Singh Choudhary</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ccode4u. The example have made me to describe the issue in a better way. can you see separate div function for both the cards '<div class="card">' i don't want that to happen can i put that into a loop or use something else in order to generate multiple cards.

Comment: yes and if my answer helpful to you then mark as right :)

Comment: can you suggest me with any other function to make my code shorter ?

Comment: you can do it with loop

Comment: can you give me any example using loop so that i can refer that ?

Comment: Yes sure, i hope you will be back with the example.@Ccode4u